# How to just deploy a app without baking an instance in spinnaker?

Tags: spinnaker

I am looking for some thing like Amazon Code Deploy In-place deployments. Where you deploy with out actually baking the instance again. Was not able to find any documentation on doing it. Any help and inputs are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Stage "Find Image from Tags" and use the Parameter "AMI_NAME".In Value field add the "AMI ID". In this case Spinnaker will skip the AMI baking and use the AMI you defined for Deployment.